# Coldfusion datasource pre-generation

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, datasource

I'm trying to automate server spin-up as much as possible (big component, puppet) but one of the roadblocks is having a neo-datasource.xml file ready for when ColdFusion starts. I'd like to have one generated and in place for Puppet to source before I even turn a new server on. I would very much like to avoid starting the server, going to the Administrator page, creating the datasource, and copying the datasource to Puppet.

Does anybody know a way I can pre-generate a neo-datasource.xml file? I probably just need the password encryption scheme, but I haven't been able to figure out what it is. Any method that works would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but [this blog entry](http://www.talkingtree.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/3/1/Adding-Data-Sources-to-ColdFusion-When-You-Dont-Have-the-Password) discusses copying segments of the neo-datasource.xml file from server-to-server. More importantly, it makes mention that you can copy the entire file from server-to-server.

It stands to reason that you should be able to use the file from one server to set up the new server in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is Adobe's page on the xml config files:

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/purpose-location-xml-configuration-files.html